# Iterate through an array of objects with conditional string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the easiest way to iterate through an array of objects, check if an object attribute's string contains a word and then keep the results that match?

I thought this would work:

```
@events = @events.map {|n| n if n.game.to_s.include?(game.to_s)}.compact
```

but I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

n.game can either equal nil or a string like "Pokemon, MarioKart".

Comment: That means that `@events` is nil. Also, check out http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/keep_if

Comment: Better yet why not just use query methods and off load the work to SQL then `@events` does not need to load everything just to remove objects later. If you post the code that sets `@events` initially this shouldn't be a difficult task to help with.

Comment: There isn't a method called `includes?` either. Do you mean `include?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want #select, which is also known as #find_all. That does what you want, not needing to do a map followed by a compact, just use `find_all`

```
matching_events = @events.find_all {|e| n.game.to_s.include?(game.to_s) }
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all

However, if you're getting `undefined method map for nil:NilClass`, it means that you don't have an object in your `@events` variable. Your code would work too, if you actually had an array to filter in @events. You have to set it to the array you want to filter, before you can filter it.